# SQLAlchemy/Elixir syntax for relationships on existing databases

Tags: sql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, foreign-key-relationship, python-elixir

I'm trying to build Python models using Elixir representing tables in an existing MySQL database connected via a `mysql+pyodbc` connection string.  Elixir reflects the column structure effortlessly, but doesn't seem to be able to reflect the relationships, so now I'm trying to specify those.  I'm having a beast of a time with the syntax, both the declarative and the DSL forms.

As an example, I have a foreign key relationship across two tables (one-to-one) created with the following SQL statements:

```
ALTER TABLE db.person
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_person_id_ref_person_program_id
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES db.person_program(person_id);

ALTER TABLE db.person_program
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_person_program_id_ref_person_id
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES db.person(person_id);
```

In both tables, `person_id` is the primary key.  My sense after reading the documentation (which unfortunately focuses heavily on autocreated databases and not so much on connecting to existing ones) is that the constraint names/indexes are perhaps the problem.

I'm attempting to use a `OneToOne` or `has_one` relationship to model the first constraint, and a `ManyToOne` or `belongs_to` relationship for the second.  In each case I've tried, I've gotten errors, including instructions to use the `primaryjoin` keyword argument, but this hasn't helped either.

Relatedly, I've got a similar situation with a `OneToMany` or `has_many` relationship, defined on the database with the following SQL code:

```
ALTER TABLE db.person_by_age
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_person_by_age_id_ref_person_id
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES db.person(person_id);
```

Here, `person_id` is the primary key of the `person` table, but not of the `person_by_age` table.  This constraint gives similar errors in Elixir to the above.

Has anyone done this before?  How can I specify these relationships to use the existing foreign key constraints and indexes already in the database?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: 1) What is the error you are getting?

Comment: 2) Two tables that have PKs which are FKs to each other does not smell good in pure SQL as well. Is any of the tables using `autoincrement`?

Comment: @van: No, these tables have set PKs -- unfortunately, I can't change the data set too much.  For the first scenario, I could combine the tables, but the data in each is qualitatively different data and the latter is queried much less than the former, so I kept them apart for that reason.  In the current state:

Comment: @van: using:
`has_one('program', of_kind='PersonProgram', 
            primaryjoin='Person.person_id==PersonProgram.person_id', 
            inverse='person')`
I get:
`ArgumentError: Column-based expression object expected for argument 'primaryjoin'; got: 'Person.person_id==PersonProgram.person_id', type <type 'str'>`

I'll need to recreate prior errors.